# Comparing large Mysql table (1 column) with file line by line

Tags: php, mysql, unix, centos6

I want to perform a comparison between a 1Gb table (1 column) from MySQL and a (200Mb-2Gb) file,
get all the data from MySql which are not on the file, the file is occasionally changing.
I'm using this code in PHP

```
    $fileData = file_exists('/home/list')?explode("\n", file_get_contents('/home/list')):array();
    $bdTable = array();
    $query_data = bd::query("SELECT id_md5 FROM table WHERE addr REGEXP '$regex'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_data)){
    $Md5 = $row['id_md5'];
    if(!in_array($Md5,$json)){
    $bdTable[] = $Md5;
    $data_count3++;
    }
    }
```

but it's very slow, I was wondering if there is a faster way, it could be using PHP, centos command lines, or Mysql